# Why does vi keep replacing text?

Tags: vi

How do I stop vi from replacing text while typing? For example, in a groovy file when I type "pl" vi replaces it with "println".

Comment: what did you do to get `vi` to start replacing text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens due to abbreviations, which apparently cannot be disabled easily. Per the vim users mailing list, I've added the following to my .vimrc:

autocmd FileType * abc

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the .vimrc file? It might have the replacements there. I googled it for you and came up with [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/vim-editor-how-to-correct-spelling-mistakes-automatically/) result, which might be more complete than you want.